# I want to remove background (it is like black ring)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

This is the image i used. (retinal vessel, DRIVE database)

[image: Screenshot]

first, It through a pre-processing process. 
The pre-processing process is as follows.

1. gaussian filter is applied to remove noise. (and plot BGR histogram)

   ```
   cv::GaussianBlur(gassimg, gassimg, cv::Size(3,3),1.0, 1.0);
   ```
2. Background is replaced by average value and set the threshold. 
   (an area of size 50*50 from the center)

   ```
   for (int y = imgrow/2 -25; y < imgrow/2 +25; ++y) {
   for (int x = imgcol/2 -25; x < imgcol/2 +25; ++x) {
       b += tempimg.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x)[0];
       g += tempimg.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x)[1];
       r += tempimg.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x)[2];
       }
   }
   r = r / (2500);
   g = g / (2500);
   b = b / (2500);

   for (int y = 0; y < tempimg.rows; ++y) {
   for (int x = 0; x < tempimg.cols; ++x) { 
       if ((tempimg.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x)[0] <=30) || tempimg.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x)[1] <= 30 || tempimg.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x)[2] <= 30)
       {
           tempimg.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x)[2] = r;
           tempimg.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x)[1] = g;
           tempimg.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x)[0] = b;
       }
   }
   ```

   }

The result is as a follows.
[image]

There is one problem with this image. (like blue - circle)

The edges are made.

[image]

I want to remove the edges. (like black-ring)
What should I do?

Comment: I think the erode operation is good.

Comment: if you know any other good idea, please give me your opinion

Comment: Median filter? By the way, it's probably better to use it instead of your original GaussianBlur as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use circle hough transform to detect the big circle, then force the pixels outside the big circle zero, then you can remove the ring.

[image: sample picture]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I find a big circle using opencv's houghcircle function.

Comment: but I can't access circle's pixel value. I can't replace to zero value...

Comment: after using hooughcircle function, you can get the big circle's center and radius. let (a, b) represents the center and r represents radius, if (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 >= (r-2) ^2, then tempimg.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y) = 0

Comment: Sorry for comment is late, I finally solved this problem. Thank you!